# Automatically set file name of externalized graphics equal to the file name of the tikz/PGF file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

As the title says, is it possible to set some options for the externalize library in order to for the filename of the externalized graphics to be equal to the filename of the TikZ-file without using `\tikzsetnextfilename{}` for each and every figure that is to be externalized?

E.g. if I have a file `pendulum.tikz`, I'd like the externalized output to get the file name `pendulum.pdf` without having to explicitly specify the name using `\tikzsetnextfilename{pendulum}`.

Might be that this is specified in the manual, but then I haven't understood how this is done.

Hope someone can help.

Edit:

an "MWE" (which doesn't work as I want it to) with the TikZ-options I use per today.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{circuit}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic IEC]
    \matrix[column sep=7mm]
    {
        \node (i0) {0}; & & \\
        & \node [and gate] (a1) {}; & \\
        \node (i1) {0}; & & \node [or gate] (o) {};\\
        & \node [nand gate] (a2) {}; & \\
        \node (i2) {1}; & & \\
    };
    \draw (i0.east) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (a1.input 1);
    \draw (i1.east) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (a1.input 2);
    \draw (i1.east) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (a2.input 1);
    \draw (i2.east) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (a2.input 2);
    \draw (a1.output) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (o.input 1);
    \draw (a2.output) -- ++(right:3mm) |- (o.input 2);
    \draw (o.output) -- ++(right:3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit #2

I have have something like this in my document that I want to externalize

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \input{pendulum.tikz}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \input{circuit.tikz}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \input{somethingelse.tikz}
\end{figure}
```

I'd like the externalized graphics to have the filenames `pendulum.pdf`, `circuit.pdf`, and `somethingelse.pdf`, but without having to do it like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    tikzsetnextfilename{pendulum}
    \input{pendulum.tikz}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \tikzsetnextfilename{circuit}
    \input{circuit.tikz}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \tikzsetnextfilename{somethingelse}
    \input{somethingelse.tikz}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does `\tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname}` give the desired result?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I get a longer error from the TikZ package.

Comment: Could you clarify the situation a little, perhaps including a MWE?  Your phrase "each and every figure" suggests that there is more than one figure in the document, in which case setting the filename to the filename of the TikZ-file will clobber all but the last picture.  But maybe the pictures are included in the main file and you want them to have the name of the *included* file.  It's not all that clear what the situation is here.

Comment: I've updated the question with an MWE now.

Comment: `\newcommand\inputtikzfigure[1]{\begin{figure}[ht]\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}\input{#1.tikz}\end{figure}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once the `.tikz` file has been included in your main document using `\input`, TikZ won't know the name of the file that the code came from. The easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do might be to define a new command like

```
\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
    \input{#1.tikz}%
}
```

Then you can include your images using something like `\includetikz{pendulum}`.

---

If you want to keep your input and output files in separate folders, you can simply add the necessary paths to the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

% Define the command. Note that the input and output folders are static!
\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{images_OUT/#1}%
    \input{images_INP/#1.tikz}%
}

% Create a test .tikz file in the images_INP folder
\begin{filecontents}{images_INP/circle.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [orange] circle [radius=3cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\includetikz{circle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great idea! BUT: I want to load from a subfolder 'images'. Therein are all my .tikz files. How can your command be modified to get it worked? (I don't want the whole path as filename of the externalized graphic, I yust want (as above) the name of the input-file as my externalized filename)

Comment: @DavidK.: I'm not sure I understand correctly: So you want to include the `.tikz` files from a subfolder, but the generated `.pdf` files should reside in the same folder as your `.tex` file? In that case, couldn't you simply change `\input{#1.tikz}%` to `\input{subfolder/#1.tikz}`?

Comment: @Jake: e.g i run my .tex document on the desktop. Furthermore i've a folder 'images_INP' and a folder 'images_OUT' also on the desktop.
Now I want to load a .tikz file from the folder 'images_INP', compile the document and save the externalized pdf into 'images_OUT'
I tired with:

\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
\input{1-images_INP/#1.tikz}%
}
...
...
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includetikz{1-images_INP/image1}
\caption{so ein toller Würfel}
\end{figure}

but then i get:

LaTeX Error: File `1-images_INP/1-images_INP/image1.tikz' not found.

Comment: @DavidK.: Well, if you put `1-images_INP` into the macro definition, you shouldn't use it again when you call `\includetikz`. Are you looking for a solution where the input and output folders are static, i.e. you only define them when you're defining the macro, or do you want to be able to set the paths when you're calling `\includetikz`? I've edited the answer to include a way of achieving the former.

Comment: @Jake: it would be nice if my inputfolders could change and only the name of the loaded .tikz file would be important for the filenmae of the externalized one. But the edit of the upper solution is one good step in the right direction :)

Comment: In case of using `tikzscale`, the above method fails, a fix would be:
    `\newcommand{\includetikz}[2][]{
\let\oldtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\tikzsetnextfilename{images_OUT/#2}\oldtikzpicture}
\includegraphics[#1]{images_INP/#2.tikz}
\let\tikzpicture\oldtikzpicture
}`

Answer (score 1):

Quite old thread but I want to add a solution when dealing with tikz files saved in different subfolders (as @David K. in his comment to the approved answer mentions on Nov 16 '12 at 11:18):

```
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[2]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#2}%
    \input{#1#2.tikz}%
}
```

A MWE would be (just taken from the approved answer and modified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./images_OUT/]

% Define the command. Note that input folder is NOT STATIC ANYMORE!
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[2]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#2}%
    \input{#1#2.tikz}%
}

% Create a test .tikz file in the images_INP folder
\begin{filecontents}{images_INP/circle.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \fill [orange] circle [radius=3cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\inputtikz{images_INP/}{circle}

\end{document}
```

This way, circle.pdf is saved to the output folder './images_OUT'. You have to specify the output path in the command call though.