# pgfplots: Externalize file name - use figure reference (e. g. Figure 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

### Introduction

I have a document with many `pgfplots` diagrams embedded in figures. I want to generate a separate file for every diagram by using the `externalize` feature.

> Is it possible to name the generated files according to the figure
>   number?

In my real life example I have a `book` class and the figures are named e. g. Figure 4.13 (chapter 4, figure 13).

### Similar Question(s)

- [Automatically set file name of externalized graphics equal to the file name of the tikz/PGF file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57737)

### Example Code

```
\documentclass{article}
% Here just for the figure placement option "H".
\usepackage{float}

% Plotting diagrams
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Using the "Externalize" feature
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

% Configuring the "Externalize" feature
\tikzexternalize[prefix=Output/] % Save all externalized files in the subfolder "Output"
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Section}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Example Output

[image]

[image]

### Desired Output

The file named according to the figure, e. g. **Figure.1.pdf**.

[image]

### Update

I would also accept if I have to add `\tikzsetnextfilename` from the `pgf` package before every figure. **Then the question is how do I build the next figure name when using the book class?**

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because it's not what you wanted, but `external/figure name={Figure.}` and `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` could do what you want, perhaps

Comment: But when the figure number changes, your whole external figures do not match anymore - do you really want that? I'd rather use `\tikzsetnextfilename{myFigure}` before the tikzpicture and give the figure a distinct name.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the comment. I really want that. It's for non LaTeX users so that they can use the figures in other documents. With this system they can easily find the right file. So far I did it manually, for example here (German): http://bedienhaptik.de/dissertation/abbildungen-zum-download/

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I've undeleted. I think, the new version is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've prepended the `figure` environment with to set the next file name depending on the figure counter value. Even if this figure is not externalized, it will work for other ones. For a `chapter.figure` numbering style the output of `\thefigure` would be better, however.

```
\documentclass{book}
% Here just for the figure placement option "H".
\usepackage{float}

% Plotting diagrams
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Using the "Externalize" feature
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\figure}{%
  \xdef\tmp@a{Figure.\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1}% Prepare the next filename 
  \tikzsetnextfilename{\tmp@a}
}{}{}%
\makeatother
\tikzexternalize[prefix=Output/,] % Save all externalized files in the subfolder "Output"
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Section}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of Figure}
    \label{foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of Figure}
    \label{foobar}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**More configurable version** (and some explanation)

`\tikzsetnextfilename` needs to know the fully expanded filename. Either this is a string or an macro that expands to the full filename.

`\xdef\tmp@a{Figure.\the\numpexpr\value{figure}+1}` defines `\tmp@a` globally and expands it `Figure.1` or `Figure.2` etc. This is a fixed content which may be given to `\tikzsetnextfilename` (`\xdef` is the global variant of `\edef`, meaning expanded definition.

Now, the direct way without `\edef` (or `\xdef`) needs multiple `\expandafter` statements

```
\expandafter\tikzsetnextfilename\expandafter{\expandafter\myexternalprefix\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1}%
```

This is not really easier!

```
\documentclass{book}
% Here just for the figure placement option "H".
\usepackage{float}

% Plotting diagrams
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Using the "Externalize" feature
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\newcommand{\myexternalprefix}{Figure.}

\xpretocmd{\figure}{%
  \expandafter\tikzsetnextfilename\expandafter{\expandafter\myexternalprefix\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1}%
}{\typeout{figure was patched successfully}}{\typeout{figure patching failed}}%

\tikzexternalize[prefix=Output/,] % Save all externalized files in the subfolder "Output"
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Section}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of Figure}
    \label{foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption of Figure}
    \label{foobar}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will wait a bit longer until I accept the answer. I also updated the question.

Comment: Allow me a question: Does **\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1** need additional packages or works it "out of the box"? I could use that in the **\tikzsetnextfilename** command to build the correct file name.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: No, it's a `e-tex` extension/primitive and provided by the (La)TeX core already. No further packages needed. I used other packages/macro earlier but the more knowledge I have of internals, I come back/down to the primitives ;-)

Comment: It works perfectly, just implemented it today. Can you explain a bit more what's the idea behind it? When is the command executed? Do I need the tmp@a or could I just write the command as the argument for \tiktsetnextfilename?

Comment: Hi Christian - can you help me to further understand your answer? It works perfectly. Should I open a new question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I thought that I explained it further in my last edit about three weeks ago.

Comment: Sorry - my bad. So **\xpretocmd{\figure}** adds a command to the **figure** environment - do I understand that correctly? And could I use **Figure.\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1** directly in **tikzsetnextfilename **? Because I tried and I didn't get it to work.

Comment: `\xpretocmd{figure}` adds code before `\figure` starts, (`prepend`) -- I've to check the issue with `Figure.\the\numexpr...` however

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: The direct usage has its issues. It should work with a huge bunch of `\expandafter` statements. I don't recommend this