# custom names for crossref files when using tikz external

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57737/automatically-set-file-name-of-externalized-graphics-equal-to-the-file-name-of-t) suggests that to automatically set a file name of externalized graphics equal to the file name of the tikz, the following can be used:

```
\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
    \input{#1.tikz}%
}
```

If in the tikzpicture environment there is a \label, then that gets externalised as well as .dpth, .nlo, .md5, .log, .pdf files with names that look like: "main-figure_crossref0", "main-figure_crossref1", "main-figure_crossref2" etc, with increasing number (assuming the name of your document is main).

**Is there way to change the name of these crossref files such that it corresponds to the name of the tikz file as well?**

So for three figures named "PlotOfTwoCircles.tikz" (with 2 \label), "PlotOfASquare.tikz" (with 1 \label) and "PlotOfATriangle.tikz" (with 1 \label) and input in a document called "main.tex", the references files would look like: "main-PlotOfTwoCircles_crossref0","main-PlotOfTwoCircles_crossref1","main-PlotOfASquare_crossref0","main-PlotOfATriangle_crossref0" etc.

I'm assuming that this would allow one to use the includeonly command, as the crossref files would not depend on the order they appear in the document..

**EDIT**

This a MWE with `pgfplots`, `tikz`, `externalize` and `include`, as the question above is not clear.

My `main.tex` file

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzexternalize
\newcommand{\includetikz}[2]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\tikzexternalrealjob-#1#2}%
    \input{./#1/img/#2.tikz}%
}
\includeonly{ch1/ch1} % <-- This I change depending on the chapter I want to compile
\begin{document}

\include{ch1/ch1}
\include{ch2/ch2}

\end{document}
```

The directory tree:

```
thesis
│   main.tex   
│
└───ch1
│   │   ch1.tex
│   │
│   └───img
│       │   fig_with_xy.tikz
│       │   ...
│   
└───ch2
|   │   ch2.tex
│   │
│   └───img
│       │   fig_with_xy3.tikz
│       │   ...
```

The `tikz` files:

```
\begin{filecontents}{./ch1/img/fig_with_xy.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=5cm,
    height=2cm,
    at={(0,0)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=1.0,   
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ymin=0.0,
    ymax=2.0,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        1   1\\
    };
    \label{line:xy}
    \addplot [color=red, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        1   2\\
    };
    \label{line:xy2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents}



\begin{filecontents}{./ch2/img/fig_with_xy_3.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=5cm,
    height=2cm,
    at={(0,0)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=1.0,   
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ymin=0.0,
    ymax=3.0,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=black, dashed, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        1   1\\
    };
    \label{line:xydash}
    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        1   3\\
    };
    \label{line:xy3}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents}
```

The chapters

```
\begin{filecontents}{./ch1/ch1.tex}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}
        \includetikz{ch1}{fig_with_xy}
        \caption{Line of $y=x$ (\ref{line:xy}) and line of $y=2x$ (\ref{line:xy2}).}
    \end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{./ch2/ch2.tex}
    \chapter{Background}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}
        \includetikz{ch2}{fig_with_xy_3}
        \caption{Line of $y=x$ (\ref{line:xydash}) and line of $y=3x$ (\ref{line:xy3}).}
    \end{figure}
\end{filecontents}
```

Running `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex` twice, with either `\includeonly{ch1\ch1}` or `\includeonly{ch2\ch2}` produces the desired pdf assuming that no `main-figure_crossref*` files exist. If they do exist however, the references to the lines will be wrong because all the crossref files are incrementally named. This is also the case if the `\includeonly{}` line is commented out. By allowing the crossref files to get a custom name, then each chapter would be compiled independently. When the main document is compiled all together, there would be no clashing in the reference files.

I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Please provide a complete example people can compile. You really do not want to use `\includeonly{}` here. `\include{}` is meant for complete document chunks, such as chapters, and not things like images.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334250/with-tikzexternalize-how-to-name-the-images-with-the-current-name-of-the-import help at all? I now use a library version of my answer there in most documents (though not all, for some reason). But note https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42967388#42967388.

Comment: The thing is that cross-references are order-dependent, aren't they? So, if you re-order the pictures, the cross-references change. Of course, this might not be true if the relevant counters are confined to single pictures (e.g. you're labelling items in an enumeration or something), but it would if you're labelling pages, say, or using hyperref or more complex references to enumerate items, such as 'item such-and-such on page so-and-so'.

Comment: @cfr my comment on `\includeonly{}` is not clear at all..I'll add an example of my set up with `\includeonly{}` and `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @cfr I've added an example that shows when custom naming the crossref files would be useful.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense now. I try to avoid depending on this kind of thing in `tikzpicture`s as it never seems to quite work for me, but the question is much clearer, so hopefully you'll get a good answer.

Comment: It is actually `pgfplots`'s externalisation which is responsible for these files and not `tikz`'s library.

Comment: It looks doable. I think it just needs redefining the code PGF plots adds to define `\tikzappendfigurename`. However, I'm not sure what the implications of changing this might be.